# Can I share session data between app using CAS?

Tags: cas

I am newbie with [CAS Server](http://www.jasig.org/cas), I found it is a single sign on server between different application in terms of technology like php, .net & java. I explore it but even though there are some questions yet not clear. Before ask my doubt, I tell what am I trying to achieve?

I am using a gwt based application, Now for some of the features, development is in a php technology. It should get some session data from existing java application. another approach   to customize CAS like integrate a web service layer for authorization, instead of using its existing like query to db.

The doubts are:

1) Can I share a session data between Java & php application using CAS?

2) is there any security issue while passing a data using CAS server?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing session data accross application can be addressed by mechanisms not linked to CAS. Though, when authentication occurs in CAS server, user data are retrieved from various data sources and these user data can be pushed to client CAS applications through SAML validation and the appropriate configuration.